# Python attribute error: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'

Tags: python, attributeerror, gethostbyname

I am trying to do this in my program:

```
dest = socket.gethostbyname(host)
```

I have included the line:

```
from socket import *
```

in the beginning of the file.

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: type object
>   '_socketobject' has no attribute
>   'gethostbyname'

I am running Vista 64bit. Could there be  a problem with my OS? I have turned down my firewall and everything.

Answer (score 20):

You shoulod either use

```
import socket
dest = socket.gethostbyname(host)
```

or use

```
from socket import *
dest = gethostbyname(host)
```

Note: the first option is by far the recommended one.

Comment: Yayyyy!!!! It Worked!! Thanks so much, I have an assignment to be submitted tomorrow and your answer was of great help. I did not know, such a small mistake could cause such a major problem. Thanks again, I really appreciate ur quick reply.. Thanks.

Comment: @Sheela you can appreciate even more with accepting this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

After `from socket import *`, you'd need to call just the barename `gethostbyname` -- the barename `socket` now refers to a type, not to the module.  That `import *` is horrible practice, by the way: do, instead, `import socket`, and **then** `socket.gethostbyname` will work just fine!