# python socket.getservbyname is not found

Tags: python, sockets

I encountered an error on Eclipse PyDev *AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'getservbyname'* with the following code:

```
from socket import *
help(socket.getservbyname)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857146/python-attribute-error-type-object-socketobject-has-no-attribute-gethostbyn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are doing a star import, you dont have to append the module name to the method.

try this:

```
import socket
help(socket.getservbyname)
```

In case, In case you want to do a star import, which is not recommended because of namespace polluting, this is what you should be doing:

```
from socket import *
help(getservbyname)
```

Answer (score 0):

With python, you have three forms of import you can do

```
import socket
help(socket.getservbyname)
```

This form imports the whole of the socket module into your code with the same name. You then access things in it from their prefixed name

Next up:

```
import socket as othersocket
help(othersocket.getservbyname)
```

This imports the whole of the socket module into your code, but with an alternate name. You then access things from it with the alternate prefixed name

Finally:

```
from socket import *
# or
from socket import getservbyname
help(getservbyname)
```

This way, you import just specific bits from the module into your code, with their names without a prefix.

As you can hopefully see, there's a few ways to do it, you just need to be consistent about how you import vs how you use